# ARC error: receiver type for instance message does not declare a method with selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I am getting this error that I can't figure out.

> error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'pageAppViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'createContentPages'

I posted my code below. I do have a method called `createContentPages` in my class `pageAppViewController`.  What does this mean and what is causing it?

```
//  contentViewController.m

#import "contentViewController.h"
#import "pageAppViewController.h"

@implementation contentViewController

@synthesize theImageView, dataObject;
@synthesize image;

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

//error occurs on this next line    
pageAppViewController *newContent = [[pageAppViewController alloc] init];
self.image = [newContent createContentPages];
[self.theImageView setImage:  ((pageAppViewController *) [self.image objectAtIndex:0]) .images];


}

error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'pageAppViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'createContentPages'


//
//  pageAppViewController.m

#import "pageAppViewController.h"

@implementation pageAppViewController
@synthesize pageController;

@synthesize bookContent;

@synthesize images;


- (NSArray *) createContentPages
{

    UIImage *zero = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"TitlePage.png"]];
    UIImage *one = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Page1.png"]];
    UIImage *two = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Page2.png"]];
    UIImage *three = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Page3.png"]];
    UIImage *four = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Page4.png"]];
    UIImage *five = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Page5.png"]];

    NSMutableArray *pageContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
    pageAppViewController *content = [[pageAppViewController alloc] init];

    if (i == 1)
    {
        content.images = zero;
        [pageContent addObject:content];

         }

    else if (i == 2)
    {
        content.images = one;
       [pageContent addObject:content];
    }

    else if (i == 3)
    {
        content.images = two;   
        [pageContent addObject:content];
    }

    else if (i == 4)
    {
        content.images = three;
        [pageContent addObject:content];
    }

    else if (i == 5)
    {
        content.images = four;
        [pageContent addObject:content];
    }

    else if (i == 6)
    {
        content.images = five;
        [pageContent addObject:content];
    }
    }

     bookContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: pageContent];

    return bookContent;

}
```

Comment: You should show your @interface as well here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have you the

```
- (NSArray *) createContentPages;
```

Method declaration in the .h File of the Controller?

Comment: I did not have that declaration.  I just added it and it worked.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: A coworker of mine has a more recent version of LLVM and that message does not appear anymore. I cannot recall which one is, but it seems they have removed the need of declaring methods within the `@interface` is their definition and usage is limited to the `@implementation`.

Comment: yes, the new LLVM Version is more user friendly and fault tolerance. but its always a good idea to declare your methods in the @interface block with some comments.

Comment: but what if we dont want to add it into header file, without ARC it is possible, why not with ARC

Comment: but it in your "private" header declaration in your .m File